# Interpolate Matplotlib Array to an Arbitrary Length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am looking for a method of interpolating and simultaneously extending a 2D numpy array to an arbitrary length. For example say my array is

```
array = [0,0,0]
        [1,1,1]
        [2,2,2]
```

After calling the function say I want an array of length 5:

```
new_array = [0, 0, 0]
            [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]             
            [1, 1, 1]
            [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
            [2, 2, 2]
```

Ideally, this would work on any array of any length, to a new length. For example if my array was 1000 points long and I needed it to be 1500 points. Is there a way to do this easily and simply in Scipy or Numpy? I have looked through the `scipy.interpolate` module but was not able to to see how I can achieve this. Any direction would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
from scipy import interpolate

n = 5
np.column_stack([interpolate.interp1d(c,c)(np.linspace(c[:1,], c[-1:], n)) for c in arr.T])

Out[45]:
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5],
       [ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ]])
```